# OnBackButtonPressed Not Firing Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to prevent the user of my app from pressing the hardware back button.
I have found this code snippet that is in the code behind the xaml file:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

I have tried variations of this including using Boolean instead of Bool and returning `base.functionname` nothing seems to fire this method.
Here is the bigger context:

Code behind:

```
namespace Watson.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class StartScan : ContentPage
    {
        public StartScan()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second page in the stack and disabling the button only needs to happen on this page only, no where else.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this on a specific platform? Or any?

Comment: At the moment its being deployed on Android but it maybe extended to windows phones.

Comment: can you try setting this <ContentPage ....NameSpaces etc....
    NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
    Title="MyPage">
</ContentPage>

Comment: I will try this, but im sure that is for the software button only. That needs to be disabled as well so I will put this in. But I dont think its for the hardware button.

Comment: For the record, that did nothing. It didnt affect the software or the hardware button.

Comment: Can i know on which OS you are running the app ?

Comment: For now Android. Im developing in visual studio if that helps.

Comment: Neither hasbackbutton or OnBackButtonPressed works. Both seem to be ignored.

Comment: it might be problem with IDE which is not building  properly, try to Clean Project, Rebuild Project once after following code given below.

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me, I tried in Android and iOS platforms using Xamarin.Forms.

Hope you can resolve with this piece of code.

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class TestPage2 : ContentPage
    {
        public TestPage2()
        {
           NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
           InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            //return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know.

Comment: I've created test project with 2 content pages, tested it thoroughly, It is not navigating backward using hardware button also, I tried in simulator and emulator of iOS and Android respectively. :)

Comment: Sorry but it didnt work. I have xactly that, I even tried cleaning and rebuilding. One thing worth noting is that when I use the override for OnBackPressed in the MainActivity.cs (so exclusive to Android) it seems to work but for all pages, not just page 2.

Comment: you might need to update your xamarin forms package...  Anyway it worked for me. I tried in realtime device as well.

Comment: Xamarin forms is up to date. I have no idea why its not working. What I might have to do is create some class that holds a flag that indicates that the user is on page 2 then set the button on/off in MainActivity based on that flag.

Comment: Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @user3355961 Sorry for the late reply. But did you try returning false instead of true in protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed() method?

Answer (score 2):

You can also add NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton property in the XAML

```
     NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True"
```

In the Content Page

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
namespace Watson.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class StartScan : ContentPage
    {
        public StartScan()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            // you can put some actions here (for example, an dialog prompt, ...)
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it is working with the following code (Samsung Android)

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    //base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    browser.GoBack();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OnBackButtonPressed firing when you click the back button on your device, not from your navigation page, do your logic in OnDisappearing!